# Can I branch outside of the procedure (PROC/ENDP) in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

The documentation is silent about this. What would happen if I'll write the code like this and call the `bar`? Is there are any negative consequences?

```
foo PROC
    ...
    BX    lr
    ENDP

bar PROC
    B     foo
    ENDP
```

**UPDATE**

Techically it is totally legal to do such things. The code compiles and works correctly. As some people have noticed the `PROC` directive is needed for some meta-information in the object file. I am afraid that by using it in a such way (as in the example above) I can potentially "damage" this information with unknown consequences.

The description of this directive says that

> The assembler uses PROC to identify the start of a function when producing DWARF call frame information for ELF. PROC sets the canonical frame address to be R13 (SP), and the frame state stack to be empty.

I am not good at how debugger works, but if I am not mistaken the call frame means something related to the stack. As I do not use the stack in my functions I can make a conclusion that this information is not important to me. Am I right?

Comment: What chip architecture and assembler are you using?

Comment: Any negative consequences? If you program like this, you'll end up with a tangled mess.

Comment: This would be ok if the C-version of `bar` was `void bar() { foo(); }` (i.e. `bar` ends with the call to `foo`, so you let `foo` take care of returning to whoever called `bar` rather than returning to `bar` and have `bar` return to its caller). Otherwise, don't do this.

Comment: It is quite likely that real-word procedures will push registers on entry: if they do your method becomes quite dangerous.

Comment: Well I'm talking about the situation where you're implementing something entirely in assembly and have control of what is pushed and popped.

Comment: you can do anything you want in assembly, even crash the computer.  Proc and end and such are strictly for the tools and to help some humans who are trying to make assembly into a higher level language, you dont have to use them at all if you dont want, and by no means are they restricting you from doing what you want, you just need to know what they are doing to the code if anything and work with that.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with arm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotations like `PROC` are for the benefit of the tools - e.g. to indicate that the ELF symbol generated for that label should be marked as a function, rather than data. You need all that object file meta-information for linking, debugging, etc., but other than e.g. informing dynamic loaders how and where to map segments, it has no bearing on the actual code and data in execution.

To think about it another way: a function call is itself just a branch, so if it were somehow not allowed at the instruction set level to branch outside a "function", what kind of useful code could you actually write? ;)

Comment: The documentation says that "The assembler uses PROC to identify the start of a function when producing DWARF call frame information for ELF". So you're right about the meta-information. But is it really critical for debugging, linking and using loaders? I'm not very good at how debugger works.

Comment: Say you build `foo` as Thumb code - if the linker doesn't know what kind of symbol `<foo>` is and fills in `blx foo` relocations with the actual instruction address, rather than also setting the bottom bit for proper interworking, you're going to have a bad time. Then when you try to debug the unexpected crash, your debugger also tries to disassemble it as ARM instructions and shows gibberish ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's completely legal. Compilers, too, sometimes generate code like this:

```
int foo(int x)
{
    return x*x*4 + x*7 + 1;
}

int bar(int x)
{
    printf("Hello bar");
    return foo(x);
}
```

This code is very likely to be implemented as a jump to foo from within bar, instead of call and immediately return.

Comment: That's make sense. If compilers can generate such jumps, I can do that too!